# Display the long names in Finder

Tags: finder

As far as I learnt OS X allows only certain number of characters for a file name. However, I connect to a remote Linux server where the names have hundreds of characters. The Finder cannot handle it and shortens the names into something unintelligible. Is it possible to make Finder display the original long names?

Comment: Is it the filename that is so long or the path name? On the mac the path is shown on the bottom of the Finder window and the filename is listed in the window.

Answer (score 1):

If it's actually the filename that is too long you need to increase the column width for the filename. Shown below is a finder window, in list view, that is too narrow to show the filenames.[image]

By moving your cursor slowly over the line indicated, your cursor will change and you can click on the line and move it to the right to expand column views.

The image below shows the window after expanding the column.  Notice that some file names are quite long.

To my knowledge, Mac has no limit on the length of file name. However it may be 255 characters. [image]

Comment: The file name length limitation has already been addressed:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/86611/119271

Comment: @user3439894 i fell like a fool for missing that!!  thanks again